# How to use moneris test server to do transaction in php?

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I downloaded moneris php api access classes from moneris website. 
After long debugging I see that the moneris test server does not perform the transaction and it results into failure.
Later I tried to POST a xml request given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request>
  <store_id>monusqa02</store_id>
  <api_token>yesguy</api_token>
  <us_purchase>
    <order_id>12399919</order_id>
    <amount>1.00</amount>
    <pan>4242424242424242</pan>
    <expdate>1111</expdate>
    <crypt_type>1</crypt_type>
    <commcard_invoice>102012</commcard_invoice>
    <commcard_tax_amount>1.00</commcard_tax_amount>
  </us_purchase>
</request>
```

but it results into failure. Why can't I perform transaction on moneris test server.

The error response is.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
        <response>
        <receipt>
        <ReceiptId>null</ReceiptId>
        <ReferenceNum>null</ReferenceNum>
        <ResponseCode>null</ResponseCode>
        <ISO>null</ISO>
        <AuthCode>null</AuthCode>
        <TransTime>null</TransTime>
        <TransDate>null</TransDate>
        <TransType>null</TransType>
        <Complete>false</Complete>
        <Message>Cancelled: null</Message>
        <TransAmount>null</TransAmount>
        <CardType>null</CardType>
        <TransID>null</TransID>
        <TimedOut>false</TimedOut>
        <BankTotals>null</BankTotals>
        <Ticket>null</Ticket>
    </receipt>
</response>
```

Comment: What are the error messages? How does it 'fail'?

Comment: @Christopher Ashley: Can you please tell the same implementation for CANADA region. I have tried with following details but giving me above response.

*My QA host address:* https://esqa.moneris.com:443/gateway2/servlet/MpgRequest

*CANADA Test Store ID: monusqa02
CANADA Test API Token: yesguy*

Please share the request params and response what we should get for CANADA region. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue just change the store_id and the api_token in the XML. The test account monusqa02 needs and extra 0, and yesguy is actually the password for Canada test gateway the US test gateway uses an API token of qatoken instead.

Credentials to use:

- US Test Store ID: **monusqa002**
- US Test API Token: **qatoken**

Also here are a few other things to check:

- Make sure you send your test transactions to the US test host address: https://esplusqa.moneris.com:443/gateway_us/servlet/MpgRequest
- monusqa002 is a shared testing account so make sure you choose an especially unique Order ID
- Expiry dates should be in the future, and they also need to be in the format of **YYMM**
  *Note: This format YYMM is the reverse of how a date appears on a physical credit card*

Here's the new XML Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request>
  <store_id>monusqa002</store_id>
  <api_token>qatoken</api_token>
  <us_purchase>
     <order_id>123992sasasdas19</order_id>
     <amount>1.00</amount>
     <pan>4242424242424242</pan>
     <expdate>1111</expdate>
     <crypt_type>1</crypt_type>
     <commcard_invoice>102012</commcard_invoice>
     <commcard_tax_amount>1.00</commcard_tax_amount>
   </us_purchase>
 </request>
```

XML Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
   <receipt>
      <ReceiptId>123992sasasdas19</ReceiptId>
      <ReferenceNum>640000030010500400</ReferenceNum>
      <ResponseCode>001</ResponseCode>
      <ISO>00</ISO>
      <AuthCode>714328</AuthCode>
      <TransTime>13:34:26</TransTime>
      <TransDate>2014-12-18</TransDate>
      <TransType>00</TransType>
      <Complete>true</Complete>
      <Message>APPROVED*</Message>
      <TransAmount>1.00</TransAmount>
      <CardType>V</CardType>
      <TransID>804836-0_25</TransID>
      <TimedOut>false</TimedOut>
      <BankTotals>null</BankTotals>
      <Ticket>null</Ticket>
      <CorporateCard>false</CorporateCard>
      <CardLevelResult>A</CardLevelResult>
      <CavvResultCode />
   </receipt>
</response>
```